# Internet connection disconnects with no apparent reason

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a situation where one minute the internet connection on my laptop is working perfectly fine then all of a suddend, it just disconnects.
Here's an example of a ping command running when it happens:

[image]

In order for it to come back, I have to disconenct and connect to it again...then it works for a while.

Two strange things is that it only happens when im browsing the internet; if Im playing an online game for example, it works perfectly fine with 9ms ping

Also, my pc is quite far from the router so I get 3 out of 6 connection bars but when the problem happens, I get 6 bars even though there is no conection

Does anyone have an idea on what I may be facing?

Comment: Move your PC into the same room as the router and try. It is probably your signal. Better yet, run a wire instead of using WiFi. It doesn't have these sort of problems until you get very far away. Otherwise, setup another hot spot between you and the router.

Comment: thanks krowe, it only happens when I'm far away, but what I don't understand is that it didn't happen during around 6 months then all of a sudden it started to happen.

what would I have to do to add another hot stop?

Comment: Look for a 'wireless range extender'. Any WiFi router should be able to do this as well. Or just get a cable and really solve the problem for much less. The further you get from our device the greater impact interference has. Your neighbor may have gotten a new refrigerator or other high power device and it is what is now causing your troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us how you get the internet into your house. Is it ADSL (through the phone line), Mobile 3G broadband (with SIM card) or Cable.

As you are pinging a server on the internet is means there is lots of connection points involved, if could be anything from the switch at your local exchange, wiring underground from the exchange to your house, wiring in your house, modem, wifi circuit in the the router, wifi card in your laptop, other hardware in your laptop which goes towards contributing to the networking. Or it could be software that can involve it self in the networking.

This is where some good troubleshooting needs to come in to eliminate what is good and what is bad.

Here are some basic things to try:
1. Connect your laptop to someone elses WIFI (I am assuming your computer is on wifi at the moment back your modem). Re-ping to the same IP and watch the results. This will work out whether the issue is with your laptop or your home network. To be sure you should try on another network again so you reproduce the result, and ensure you didn't just get a false positive which leads you marching off down the wrong path.

2. Once you have established if it is your laptop or your network come back and add a comment.

Comment: hey thanks, its ADSL and it works fine on other WIFIs. I believe it may be a distance problem, but as I said, this problem it didn't happen for 6 months then all of a sudden it started to happen. There was no change on the internet plan so I'm wondering if it may be something my computer is doing (I have a-virus on all the time so I dont think its a virus)